# What should I do after a cmake error occurred?

Tags: software-installation

I want to install software from source after git clone.
The author provided the following steps to install it:

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
mkdir build;cd build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
```

but when I go into the step `cmake ..` ,the error occurs:

```
    -- checking for module 'purple'
    --   package 'purple' not found
    CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:279 (message):
      A required package was not found
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:333 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
      CMakeLists.txt:18 (pkg_check_modules)


    -- checking for module 'glib-2.0'
    --   package 'glib-2.0' not found
    CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:279 (message):
      A required package was not found
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:333 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
      CMakeLists.txt:19 (pkg_check_modules)


    -- checking for module 'mozjs185'
    --   package 'mozjs185' not found
    CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:279 (message):
      A required package was not found
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:333 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
      CMakeLists.txt:20 (pkg_check_modules)


    libpurple version:Package purple was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `purple.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'purple' found
    libpurple version outdate
    -- checking for module 'libcurl'
    --   package 'libcurl' not found
    CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:279 (message):
      A required package was not found
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:333 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
      liblwqq/CMakeLists.txt:29 (pkg_check_modules)


    -- checking for module 'sqlite3'
    --   package 'sqlite3' not found
    CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:279 (message):
      A required package was not found
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:333 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
      liblwqq/CMakeLists.txt:30 (pkg_check_modules)


    CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:38 (INSTALL):
      install TARGETS given no LIBRARY DESTINATION for module target "webqq".


    ===============================================
    -- With Libev (Option)     : NO
    -- Native Language Support : true
    -- Install Path            : 
    ===============================================
    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

And after I installed the glib-2.0 and sqlite3 packages, the error message doesn't change!

What's more, the command `sudo apt-get install purple` doesn't work.

So, what should I do to finish installing this software?

Comment: Could you provide the link which such instructions?

Answer (score 1):

To build program that depends on some libraries you need to install **development** packages for those libraries.
Development packages usually named same as library, but with `-dev` on the end, e.g. `libpurple-dev` for `libpurple`, `libsqlite3-dev` for `libsqlite3` etc.

According to your log you need to install:

```
apt-get install libpurple-dev libglib2.0-dev libmozjs185-dev \
    libsqlite3-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev
```